# Using eval in Node.js to send requests to the server using submit button and input text

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So here is what I'm trying to achieve!

I want to create a very simple Node application where I can make use of the `eval` function by creating a input text box and a submit button. I want to be able to write things in the text box and when hitting submit to use the `eval` function to send this parameter to the server.

So if I write `while(true)` in the text box this should cause a DoS attack to the server, due to the `eval` vulnerability.

Here is my code so far (fix doesn't work properly)

```
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(function(request, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"}); 
  res.write("<html>");
  res.write("<head>");
  res.write("<title>Hello World Page</title>");
  res.write("</head>");
  res.write("<body>");
  res.write("Enter Some text");

  res.write('<input type="text" name="fname">');

  res.write('<input type="submit" value="Submit")');

  var parameter = eval(req.body.fname); 
  res.send(parameter);
  res.write("</body>"); 
  res.write("</html>");
  res.end();
});

server.listen(1337);
console.log("Server is listening");
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: So how exactly doesn't it work? If you type something and submit, what happens ?

Comment: Well, I think something in the code is wrong, specially the eval(req.body.fname) because the submit button is not linked to the eval parameter, so when hitting submit, it should pass the written text in the input to the eval, but thats the point where Im kind of lost.

Comment: The `req.body` property is not part of the native HTTP module, it's part of the Express library. You will need to read from the request stream in order to get form data.

Comment: Can you give me an example please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - here is a good post on the topic: [Accessing the HTTP message body (e.g. POST data) in node.js](http://blog.frankgrimm.net/2010/11/howto-access-http-message-body-post-data-in-node-js/)

A couple of minor changes to your html:

- I've added a form element with an action and method set to POST.  You could use GET as well to avoid some of the `req.on(...)` logic below.
- added closing bracket for the submit button - you had a typo with a paren

When reading posted form data, you will need to read all of the data coming in until it is complete.  The req parameter is an event emitter so you would use:

```
req.on('data', function(chunk) {...}
req.on('end', function() {...}
```

To buffer up the incoming data then act on it when the end of the request is reached.

The form data is encoded, so you will need to parse it using the querystring module.

I've also added just enough error checking (and fixed a few naming bugs) to get the code to function at a basic level.

Code:

```
var http = require("http");
var querystring = require('querystring');
var util = require('util');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var body = "";
  req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    body += chunk;
  });
  req.on('end', function () {
    console.log('POSTed: ' + body);

    body = querystring.parse(body);
    console.log('decoded: ' + util.inspect(body));

    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    res.write("<html>");
    res.write("<head>");
    res.write("<title>Hello World Page</title>");
    res.write("</head>");
    res.write("<body>");
    res.write("Enter Some text");

    res.write('<form action="/" method="post">');
    res.write('<input type="text" name="fname">');

    res.write('<input type="submit" value="Submit">');
    res.write('</form>');

    if(body.fname) {
      var parameter = eval(body.fname);

      console.log(util.inspect(parameter));
      if(parameter) {
        res.write(parameter);
      }
    }
    res.write("</body>");
    res.write("</html>");
    res.end();
  });
});

server.listen(1337);
console.log("Server is listening");
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Your help was much apreciated